# Dask: Visualize dask task graph of nested delayed functions

Tags: python, dask, pygraphviz, dask-delayed

For the following toy example, I am attempting to parallelize some nested for loops using dask delayed/compute. Is there any way I can visualize the task graph for the following?

```py
import time

from dask import compute, delayed


@delayed
def child(val):
    time.sleep(1)
    return val


@delayed
def p1(val):
    futs = []
    for i in range(5):
        futs += [child(val * i)]
    return compute(*futs)


@delayed
def p2(val):
    futs = []
    for i in range(10):
        futs += [p1(val * i)]
    return compute(*futs)


@delayed
def p3(val):
    futs = []
    for i in range(30):
        futs += [p2(val * i)]
    return futs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = p3(10)
    f.visualize()
```

For example, when I call the `.visualize` method on any of the delayed functions it returns just one level(node?) but none of the previous branches and functions. For instance `p3(10).visualize()` returns

[p3 task graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v1zR.png)

Perhaps I am using `dask.delayed` improperly here?

Answer (score 1):

Building off Sultan's example above visualize(p3(10)) returns the following [task graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMSN9.png)

Instead if you modify the return to be a sum instead of a list:

```
import time

from dask import compute, delayed, visualize


@delayed
def child(val):
    time.sleep(1)
    return val


def p1(val):
    return sum([child(val * i) for i in range(2)])


def p2(val):
    return sum([p1(val * i) for i in range(3)])

def p3(val):
    return sum([p2(val * i) for i in range(4)])
```

It returns the following [task graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSz5W.png)

Perhaps my question should have been, what the blank boxes in the task graph represent?

Comment: The rectangles represent the results of the functions ( and the functions are represented by circles), this is how Dask's task graphs are visualized everywhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

`dask.visualize` will show the task DAG, however without evaluating the contents of a delayed task, dask will not know what to plot (since the results are delayed). Running `compute` within the delayed function doesn't resolve this, since this will be done only once the task itself is evaluated.

Referring to the [best practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/delayed-best-practices.html), you will want to avoid calling `delayed` within `delayed`.

The snippet below shows one way to modify the script:

```py
import time

from dask import compute, delayed, visualize


@delayed
def child(val):
    time.sleep(1)
    return val


def p1(val):
    return [child(val * i) for i in range(2)]


def p2(val):
    return [p1(val * i) for i in range(3)]


def p3(val):
    return [p2(val * i) for i in range(4)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = p3(10)
    visualize(f)
    # by default the dag will be saved into mydask.png
```

Comment: This is a good answer, Sultan! One thing I'd add, we'll need to call `compute(f)` in the end to compute the results. Also, I'm not seeing the task graph on `visualize(f)` (or `visualize(*f)`) -- any idea why? (I'll follow up if I figure it out!)

Comment: By default, the viz is saved into a `my_dask.png`.

Comment: Yeah, that file is empty for me, no graphs :/

Comment: Hmm, that's odd...

Comment: Thanks Sultan, visualize(f) works for me in ipynb if I call it from another cell. However the task graph was different from what I expected, with all of the child functions in parallel with no branches or nodes. When I modified the toy example to return a sum rather than a list this showed the tree structure I was expecting.

Comment: Following up, my package installs were broken, it works perfectly now. :)